# iphone app - dynamic functionality allowed?

Tags: iphone

I re-framed this question from before to be a little simpler:

Is it allowed to have dynamic functionality in your iphone app i.e. connect to our servers and see what functionality should be downloaded and run on this instance of the app for a specific customer?

Please ask questions if you don't understand what we are after here. Thanks.

Comment: are you talking about something like checking for available speech recognition grammars in an ASR application?  that is probably OK, but I'm pretty sure that downloading any code and then, say, running it inside of an interpreter would be a no-no. this sounds like it might be quite iffy though, so you'd be best off contacting apple and trying to get an answer from them directly.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. 
What I mean is this: say you have an app that you log on to. having logged on, the app connects to our servers to see what functions should be available to you, then allow those functions to be run. Like an App Framework if you will, where depending on what your user account says you have access to, you will have access to.

Answer (score 0):

You are only allowed to downlad code or functionality through the In-App Purchase mechanism. The code or functionality enablers must reside on your own servers, or in the iOS itself, but the availability check must go through the In-App system.

It is however also possible to enable certain features in your application based on external subscriptions, etc. This can for instance be seen in the TripIt application, where "Pro" account holders have access to more functionality. If you decide to go down that path you should thread very carefully since Apple may decide to reject your application if for instance buttons appears dimmed because the user have not been granted access to a certain feature. The way TripIt seems to have "circumvented" this is simply to completely hide this information to the non-Pro user.

Comment: Thanks very much for this answer. I just want to make sure I have understood you correctly:

1) This implies that there's no way of having "plugins" to iphone apps i.e. small chunks of code that gets downloaded from our servers when running the app. Correct?

2) With your approach, the problem is that if you have ALL functions in your ONE app, as soon as one of the functions need an update, you need to update the app. That can lead to a LOT of updating.

Thanks much for taking the time with this. It is much appreciated.